# Python Json Access Data

Tags: python, json

I have Json data as below:

```
{
 "context":[ 
            {   
             "local": 
                    [
                      {
                       "interface": "BDI200",
                       "desc":"eNODEB",
                      },

                       {
                      "interface": "BDI100",
                      "desc":"eNODEB",
                      }
                   ]

                 },

            {
               "CPM": [
                       {

                       "interface": "BDI200",
                       "desc":"eNODEB",
                       },

                      {
                       "interface": "BDI100",
                       "desc":"eNODEB",
                       }
                 ]
         }
   ]
}
```

Actually within 'context' I have two context 'local' and 'CPM'. To access elements of context I have to statically names of context (for example my code below). In real life I have more than 50 context then How do I access without giving names.

```
import json


a=open('4.txt','r')
data=json.load(a)
print (data['context'][0]['local'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your json is not valid,

I made a valid json out of the one in question like below,

```
{
 "context":[ 
            {   
             "local": 
                    [
                      {
                       "interface": "BDI200",
                       "desc":"eNODEB"
                      },

                       {
                        "interface": "BDI100",
                        "desc":"eNODEB"
                      }
                   ]

                 },

            {
               "CPM": [
                       {

                       "interface": "BDI200",
                       "desc":"eNODEB"
                       },

                      {
                       "interface": "BDI100",
                       "desc":"eNODEB"
                       }
                 ]
         }
   ]
}
```

if you want to iterate over this json and get all local, CPM etc try this,

```
import json


a=open('4.txt','r')
data=json.load(a)
for k in data:
    for j in data[k]:
        d = j
        for l in d:
            print(l)
            print(d[l])
```

Answer (score 0):

Context is an array in your case so you can simply iterate over it:

```
for cntxt in data["context"]:
    print(cntxt)
```

If you have control on the json structure you can change it this way:

```
{
    "context":
    {   
        "local": [
            {
                "interface": "BDI200",
                "desc":"eNODEB",
            },
            {
                "interface": "BDI100",
                "desc":"eNODEB",
            }
        ],

        "CPM": [
            {
                "interface": "BDI200",
                "desc":"eNODEB",
            },
            {
                "interface": "BDI100",
                "desc":"eNODEB",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And iterate over it more explicitely:

```
for name, context_data in a["context"].items():
    print("Context's name:", name)
    print("Data:", context_data)
```